# Rails SQlite boolean problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, boolean

I am running Rails 3.0.9 and SQlite3 1.3.4

I have created a boolean called `is_approved` on my `photos` table.

```
add_column("photos", "is_approved", :boolean, :default => false)
```

It stores these as `'t'` and `'f'` in my database, but I have no problem with that.

I have a view which displays all records that have an `is_approved` value of "false".

```
def moderate 
  @photos = Photo.where(:is_approved => false)
end
```

This works fine too, even though the database stored `'t'`s and `'f'`s.

I run into a problem when I manually (in my db viewing app or in rails console) change a record's `is_approved` value to `true` or `false` or `t` or `f` or `1` or `0`. When I do that, the record is no longer recognized no matter how I call it.

Anyone have any thoughts? Can I clarify my issue more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is some sort of encoding issue.
Use the rails console and do:

```
photo.update_attribute(:is_approved, false)
```

Then it will go through active record.

Comment: Hm, that does change the record in my database, but I am still unable to find that record when using `.where(:is_approved => false)` or `true`...

Comment: No wait! I take that back. It seems to be working now. I think I had to update it as `true` and then update it as `false` again. I guess active record saw that it already was "true" so it ignored the update until I changed it back to false. Thanks man.